# Dynamically passing in an argument into `docker-compose.yml`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I can specify an arg in `docker-compose.yml` as follows (e.g. `RAILS_ENV`)

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
     context: .
     args:
       RAILS_ENV: production
```

The `Dockerfile` uses this `ARG` and sets an`ENV` so that my image gets built with that environment variable:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

# ...

ARG RAILS_ENV
ENV RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV

# ...
# Image contains environment variable `$RAILS_ENV` as `"production"`
```

However, what if I want to use something other than the hard-coded value of `"production"` ?

1. Is there a way to pass the variable into the `docker-compose.yml` file dynamically?
2. Additionally, can I specify a default value (e.g. `development`) in `docker-compose.yml` in case I don't pass in anything?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes and yes (with `.env` file), see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

First, you will need to create `.env` with variables (in this same location as your `Dockerfile`):

```
RAILS_ENV=production
```

You are not committing this file to the repository (You should add it to `.gitignore`).
And then you can start to use them in `Dockerfile`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
     context: .
     args:
       RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV}
```

There are two ways to define default values for variables:

> ${VARIABLE:-default} evaluates to default if VARIABLE is unset or
>   empty in the environment. ${VARIABLE-default} evaluates to default
>   only if VARIABLE is unset in the environment.

So for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
     context: .
     args:
       RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV:-development}
```

Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution